# Getting a binary string when testing an Artisan command

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm getting trouble testing an artisan command.

When I run an `assertEquals` against a `getDisplay()` output,
my test fails becouse the *expected* string is different to the *actual* binary string.

Here there are my test and the PHPUnit output: http://paste.laravel.com/15rN

What's wrong?

Comment: Show your binary string.

Comment: @sectus sorry, I guessed it wasn't relevant: 0x1b5b33326d64756d6d7956616c75651b5b306d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **[ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)** to get colorful outputs on windows and that caused the returning binary string.

I had to uninstall it by typing `ansicon -u` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's serializing the string because you have `'dummyValue'.PHP_EOL` in there. Try taking out the concatenated PHP_EOL and try again.

Also on a side note, make sure you are using the latest version of PHPUnit.

Comment: It was an *ansicon* issue, PHP_EOL seems not to be a problem, thanks anyway :)